# Need to move log files to another server location

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We are using Apache log4j for logging and rotation policy. 
We are using RollingFileAppender and MaxBackupIndex is 9. Logs are rotating fine as below.
application.log, application.log.1 , application.log.2 ,... ,application.log.9

Now requirement is, instead of overriding old logs, we need to move old logs to some specified location in another server. 
Could you please help me in this.

Regards,
Srinivas.

Comment: why don't you use a periodic file backup

Comment: You could create another appender that outputs to the backup area, but without rollover